# PHP: Лишняя итерация цикла

Tags: php, pdo

Доброго времени суток, подскажите где я не прав и в какую сторону смотреть. PHP скрипт прогоняет цикл на один раз больше чем нужно.
Сам массив:

```
$res = $db->query($qry)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

При выводе его функцией

```
print_r($res);
```

Выводит:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 18 [login] => первый [email] => 123@s.ru [password] => ghuay ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 19 [login] => 124 [email] => [password] => ) )
```

Пытаюсь вывести каждый элемент массива вот так:

```
$i=0;
while ($res[$i] != '')
{
    echo $res[$i]['id'];
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

(я слышал про инкремент)

еще пытался вывести вот так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
if ($res[$i] != ''){
    echo $res[$i]['id'];
}   
else{
    echo "Конец";
    break;
}
}
```

В результате получаю и там и там одно и тоже:

```
1819
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /storage/ssd4/008/2124008/public_html/index.php on line 8
```

Делаю вывод что условие срабатывает и третий раз, хотя по логике не должно. То есть `$res[0]['id'] = 18, $res[1]['id'] = 19`, а `$res[2]['id']` уже нету, следовательно должен выполниться блок else и прерваться цикл, но он выполняется, а потом прерывается.

Comment: `foreach()` http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Надо учитывать сколько у вас элементов в массиве. Их всего два, а вы пытаетесь открыть третий и т.д. Функция sizeof() вам в помощь.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($res); $i++){ //проходим в цикле от нуля до количества елементов в масиве
    echo $res[$i]['id']; //каждый раз вывоим елемент масива
    echo '<br/>'; //делаем перенос для того что бы каждый елемент масива был с новой строки
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает замечательно. Я уже решил немного по своему, но очень полезными оказались sizeof() / count().